# Where is VB.NET's MsgBox function defined?

Tags: vb.net, clr

This is really more of an academic question, but where is this function defined?  Within .NET, I'm used to working in an object oriented manner.  However, if I define a VB.NET class as follows:

```
Public Class foo
    Public Sub showmessagebox()
        Dim i As Integer
        i = MsgBox("Message")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is MsgBox defined in a class?  I am not required to reference a static class or inherit from another class.  I'm not even required to import a namespace.  I did find this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from msdn. But my question remains,  where is this defined and how does the CLR just load up a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter `MsgBox` into Visual Studio and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, you will see that it is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, in the `Interaction` module.

In fact, this information is also available (although a bit hidden) at the bottom of the MSDN page you referenced:

> **Namespace**: Microsoft.VisualBasic
>   **Module**: Interaction
>   **Assembly**: Visual Basic Runtime Library (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

If you look into the `References` section of your project properties, you'll see that the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace is automatically imported. Since `Interaction` is a module, you can use its methods without having to qualify the module name (as opposed to static/Shared methods of a class).

As a side note: If you add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to a C# project, you can use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Hello World");` there as well (although most C# users will prefer using the `MessageBox` class).

Comment: Thank you Heinzi, Modules was the key word here.  Apparently I've been in C# and out of VB.NET for too long.